# LED monitor takes about 10 minutes to power on

Tags: display, power-supply, power, led

Recently, I have started to face this problem: I power on my monitor and PC, and there's no LED light on my Asus LED monitor (ASUS VH197). I have to wait for 5-10 minutes for the screen to show up after it's powered. This used to happen rarely - like once in a month, but now it seems to happen more often - once in a week or 2.

There also is another issue, where I turn on my PC, it starts, but within 5-10 seconds it turns off. I have to power it on again - then it works fine. I have a feeling that this could have to do with my power button on the cabinet.

My setup is about 7 years old, except for the PSU being just 2.5 years old.

PS: I don't keep my PC/monitor on standby - I switch on/off the power supply every time. Also, once the PC has booted up, there aren't any problems with either of the 2 hardwares.

Comment: Sounds like either moisture in the monitor or its power supply is dying. The large capacitors in monitor power supplies tend to degrade over time so it may be that unless you open up the monitor to replace them you might need to look for a new monitor.

Comment: I live in Mumbai, high humidity, and rainy season was here. So that could be it. Will the damage be irrecoverable if I don't try to fix it right away? Or I can do it at my convenience, later, no matter it's completely dead or not?